# Android Storing AV files

Tags: android

Can we able to store recorded files in hidden form apart from SDcard in android.It should be shown only to particular user and third party should not open the recorded files(ie-songs,images,messages)

Comment: Could your question be made any clearer?

Comment: I have to know other options to store the recorded data apart from SD card

Answer (score 0):

AV files included in your res-folder are usable only by the application. Afaik there is no other way.